# MVC 2 deployment in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am working on a MVC 2 application. I deployed an MVC 2 application to IIS 7 and it doesn't work. This is the first time deploying MVC application. I believe I configured it well, but get blank page.

Can someone suggest what might be wrong with the configuration? I checked the error log and got the below error message:

```
Event code: 3008 
Event message: A configuration error has occurred. 
Event time: 7/24/2013 1:23:10 PM 
Event time (UTC): 7/24/2013 5:23:10 PM 
Event ID: b5b4917c2d644626aa06e90e9d31cbca 
Event sequence: 1 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-1-130191601896341853 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Yahrzeit\ 
    Machine name: YUIAEVT2K802 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 3984 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\Yahrzeit 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
    Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'MvcYahrzeit' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

Could not load file or assembly 'MvcYahrzeit' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
```

The deployment server is 64bit.

Comment: "A blank page" is definitely not enough information. Maybe you can find a more specific error message in the windows/application log? It sounds like a missing DLL, but there are too many options with the information you've given.

Comment: This is typically a problem with the build target type.  You are probably building a 64 bit exe for a 32 bit server, or specifying any CPU when specifying a specific platform type.